# Q : Is this vector subspace? and dimension of vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Q :Is a set A = {p(x)$\in$$\mathbb{P_{2n}}$|p(-x)=-p(x)} vector subspace of Vector space $\mathbb{P_n}$
if the set A is a vector subspace of Vector space $\mathbb{P_n}$ then, what is the dimension of vector subspace?

My thought : $p_1$(x), $p_2$(x)$\in$A and $\alpha$,$\beta$$\in$$\mathbb{R}$ $\Rightarrow$ $p_1$(-x)=-$p_1$(x),$p_2$(-x)=-$p_2$(x) $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha$$p_1$(-x)=-$\alpha$$p_1$(x), $\beta$$p_2$(-x)=-$\beta$$p_2$(x) $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha$$p_1$(-x)+$\beta$$p_2$(-x)=-$\alpha$$p_1$(x)+-$\beta$$p_2$(x) $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha$$p_1$(x)+$\beta$$p_2$(x) $\in$ A

$\Rightarrow$ A is a vector subspace of Vector space $\mathbb{P_n}$

But I don't know about method of the dimension of vector subspace of A

All I know is definition of the dimension. Should I approach it assuming a basis?

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Try doing basis for specific small $n$ and what do you notice about the polynomials in $A$ vs those in the ambient $P_{2n}$.

Comment: Please use MathJax. You can find a tutoral on the help page.

Answer (score 0):

First this is a vector subspace:

$(\alpha p_1+p_2)(-x) = \alpha p_1(-x)+ p_2(-x)=-\alpha p_1(x)-p_2(x) = -(\alpha p_1+p_2)(x)\Rightarrow$ $A$ is a vector subspace of Vector space $\mathbb{P}_n.$

How $A = \{ p(x) \in \mathbb{P_{2n}}:p(-x)=-p(x) \},$ then a element of $\mathbb{P}_{2n}$ is $p(x) = a_0+a_1x+\cdots a_{2n}x^{2n}$. The condition $p(-x)=-p(x)$ implies $-p(x) = -a_0-a_1x-\cdots -a_{2n}x^{2n} = p(-x) = a_0-a_1x+a_2x^2-a_3x^3+\cdots -a_{2n-1}x^{2n-1}+a_{2n}x^{2n}.$

so comparing the two sides of the above equality, you see that the terms of odd indices cancel each other out, and so
$$ 2a_0+2a_2x^2+2a_4x^4+ \cdots 2a_{2n}x^{2n} = 0,$$
this implies $a_0 = a_2 = a_4 = \ldots =a_{2n}=0.$
so the shape of $p(x)$ is $p(x) = a_1x+a_3x^2+\cdots +a_{2n-1}x^{2n-1}$. The set $\{x,x^3,x^5, \cdots, x^{2n-1}\}$ is basis of $A$, therefore its dimension is $n$.

Comment: why 2$a_0$+2$a_2x^2$+...+2$a_{2n}x^2$ implies $a_0$=$a_2$=$a_4$=...=$a_{2n}$?
I vaguely know that it's because of the linear independence. Thank you

Comment: the zero on the right side indicates the polynomial whose coefficients are all null, then just compare the coefficients one by one to conclude that all are null. you can also conclude this from the linear independence of monomials $x^i$, as you yourself said.